# Convert jquery script to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the script I have:

I would like to convert it to pure JavaScript, so I won't have to use jQuery.

```
if ( $('#movie.playing').length ) {

    $('.settings').click();

    $('<style> .element { display: none; } </style>').appendTo(document.head);

    $('.item').click(function() {
        if ($(this).text().trim() === "Ann") {
            if ($(this).attr('aria-checked') == 'true') {
                $('.element').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('.element').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var movie = document.querySelector("#movie_player.playing-mode");
if ( movie ) {

    document.querySelector(".settings").click();

    var style = document.createElement("text/css");
    style.styleSheet.cssText = ".element { display: none; }";
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    document.querySelector(".item").click(function() {
        /* what do I do with this part? */
        if ($(this).text().trim() === "Ann") {
            if ($(this).attr('aria-checked') == 'true') {
                $('.element').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('.element').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

I don't know how to convert the if-statement, where on click of the button with text "Ann" it is going to switch the elements from `display: block` to `none` and vice versa.

Comment: You say that "*[you] would like to convert [the script] to pure JavaScript*" - so how far did you get, and where did you get stuck? What did you come up with? Where's your code?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have edited the question to show what I have so far.

Comment: Why would you do that? The main reason to use jquery isn't ease but compatibility which would take a lot of ' if else stuff ' if you were to implement it yourself.At the end you would end with a lot more code which isn't tested enough but ofc. if you just converting this single snippet then it's no problem

Answer (score 2):

1. $(selector) = document.querySelector(selector)
2. $(selector).click() = document.querySelector(selector)(maybe cache the element first).addEventlistener(eventType, fn)
3. css stuff can be add as 'class' like el.classList.add(someClassName).

**UPDATE**

It's better to get the basic knowledge with [JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Personal it's  easy than jQuery.

Comment: note that `addEventlistener` is supported from IE 9 upwards

Comment: I have edited the question with your suggestions, just the if-statement is left to be converted.